# How to change Datasource from custom cell class

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, oop

this should be straight forward but i m finding hard time in understanding. 
i have a class

```
class Field:NSObject {
    var name:String?
    var answer:String?
    .................
}
```

Now i also have a viewcontroller in which there is a tableview. I am using **Field** array as datasource for this tableview. i am passing relavent object from **Field** array to my custom cell class (see below) which have a UItextfield .

```
cell.field = self.fields[indexPath.row]
```

What i want is that when text inside UItextfield is changed this should update our main **Field** array. Also custom cell class should have fresh copy of Field instance. I hope i have made it clear, please ask if you didn't understand anything. Much obliged.

here is cell class code

```
class SpeechCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {
public var field:Field?{
    didSet{
        self.lblField.text = self.field?.name
        self.txtAnswer.placeholder = self.field?.name
    }
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField, reason: UITextFieldDidEndEditingReason) {
    self.field?.answer = textField.text!
    self.commandDelegate?.didUpdateField(field: self.field!, textField: textField)
}

override func prepareForReuse() {
    self.txtAnswer.text = self.field?.answer
}
```

here is code for tableview

```
func didUpdateField(field: Field, textField: UITextField) {
    self.fields[textField.tag].answer = textField.text!
}
```

Comment: where is your textfield? in cell? give one example for better understanding.

Comment: Yes. UItextfield is in the cell.

Comment: All of its delegates are in the cell

Comment: i have edited the question please check

Comment: You can use NotificationCenter at  didUpdateField --OR-- make array Global , by declaring it above Class

Comment: I figured it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use custom delegate method to notify the view controller about the changes in the textfield. In the custom delegate method you should update the `fields` array. You should change the `field` in the cell too before calling the custom delegate method.

You should call this delegate method in the `textFieldDidChangeText`.

Comment: This is what i am currently doing, i am updating fields array from cell via custom delegate, but somehow the field instance inside the cell is not getting fresh copy from array.

Comment: have you assigned the text delegate to self in the cell? If yes then is the method is getting called? print something there and check

Comment: Yes obviously, Problem is with prepareForReuse. It doesn't gets fresh value of field instance

Comment: okay by the fresh value you mean for new cell there should be new value? I thought you meant edited value as the fresh value. Please clarify.

Comment: After i changed dataset , in prepareForReuse i should receive new value for current instance of Field. But it return empty value.

Comment: okay so the issue is that in prepareForReuse, the field will not yet have been set so it will be nil. You have to set the answer in the didSet of field if the answer is a valid value(not empty string).

Comment: Omg! Why i didnt think of that! Honest mistake! Thanks Bro (Y)